# how to write hover in same class in css file for react js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

[image] [image]

This is a reactjs project, Te amperzand syntax is working fine in Javascript file but not in css.

How to write hover class in css file?

Comment: The way you are trying to write is called scss. A preprocessor for css. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-style-with-sass-scss-in-react/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write in same class. You should use Sass/Scss.

Save the css file with .scss extension. It is a precprocessor for better syntax.

Refer this sandbox:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-uwktzj?file=src%2FApp.js

Answer (score 1):

You must write it this way

```css
.baseStyle {
 /* base styles goes here*/

}

.baseStyle:hover {
/* hover styles goes here */
}
```

If you wish to attain what you intend you must use `scss`.

Then it will be like

```
.class {
    margin:20px;
    &:hover {
        color:yellow;
    }
}
```

### Reference

1. [Using Scss in React](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-sass-stylesheet/)

Comment: It's not working, also my question is `how to write that in same class`

Comment: You cannot write it using normal css in same place. This is how css works.

Comment: Then why it is working in js like this `':hover': {
      background: '#40a9ff'
    }`

Comment: It was working in js fine but not getting how to write the same in css, The formal method you answered is also not working.

Comment: You must understand that css and js have different syntax. You simply cannot expect it to work by copy pasting. Please take a look at the reference provided now.